# What does "1.$" mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm printing a variable using cout in Visual C++ 2010 and it shows "1.$". What does it mean?

Google does not allow searches with `$` so I couldn't find the meaning.

EDIT:

The code is like this:

```
double func(...);

std::cout << func(...);
```

I haven't modified cout's defaults

Comment: Wanna show the code? Otherwise we could guess you are displaying an amount without decimals, and with a trailing currency code?

Comment: As it is a double I am guessing positive infinity.

Comment: and what is inside the func()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936744/are-dollar-signs-allowed-in-identifiers-in-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its an infinite value with the precision set small:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()() << "\n";

    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() << "\n";
}
```

This should print:

```
1.#INF
1.#QNAN
1.$
1.$
```

#### Edit:

From @ZoogieZork in the comments below (who pointed out that it was a precision problem).
This is directly related to this: [What does floating point error -1.#J mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean)

Comment: @Kirll: Not all systems are conformant.  That is why I ask the question.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hthw3cb(v=VS.100).aspx) is conformant.

Comment: @Krill: Are you sure it is not affected by locale or other factors? I ask because I am not sure I am grasping at straws.

Comment: I think you've nailed it -- `1.#INF` when "rounded-up" to one decimal place probably ends up as `1.$` since `$` is one character higher than `#`, the same way `1.#INF` ends up as `1.#J` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean

Comment: And now that I think about it, `1.#QNAN` is probably more likely as to what it really is.

Comment: @ZoogieZork: You were correct. It could be any of the non numerical values.

Comment: @Martin, I hadn't thought about locale, probably you are right.

Answer (score -2):

$ has no special meaning in C++.

You are printing a string that contains $.

Comment: The function returns a double!

Comment: A previous poster has suggested that it is returning the ascii equivalent of the dollar sign (0x24).  If so, the value is being converted to a string....which contains dollar sign.