# Homework: Cout incorrectly handling a return value of 0.0 from a class method

Tags: c++, double, cout

*First, this is homework, so I can not dynamically allocate memory for an array of any size, and I can not use a* `vector`.

I have a class which includes a `double` array holding 30 elements, and two other variables to keep track of how many elements have been added and the max number of elements that can be stored.

There are several methods that return the highest, lowest, average, and total from the elements in the array. An example of one of the methods is...

```
double Stats::sum() const
{
  double sum = 0.0;

  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < nElements; ++i)
    sum += stats[i];

  return sum;
};
```

In my `main()` function I have a `cout` statement...

```
cout << "\nTotal rainfall for " << MonthlyRainfall.size() << " months is "
     << MonthlyRainfall.sum() << " inches.\n";
```

When there are values in the array, the output is what I expect...

```
Total rainfall for 1 months is 1.5 inches.
```

However, when there are no values in the array (the method returns 0.0), but the output looks like...

```
Total rainfall for 0 months is -1.$ inches.
```

Can anyone help me understand what's happening in the `cout` statement that's causing the 0.0 returned by my method to output as it is?

**Note:** At the beginning of the main() function, the following statement is executed to format the decimal output. `cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);`

---

> ***Update***
>   I guess it was late and I was calling the average() method instead of sum(). I have fixed it and you also pointed out that I needed to make a couple changes to the average method to ensure a divide by 0 is not happening. (=

---

Comment: I' m guessing that average() is dividing by zero and returning inf, which would display strangely on cout.

Comment: Show us the `average()` method.

Comment: +1 for clearly stating that this is homework and what you have to work with. One thing though: in your cout you print the result for `average`, yet you are posting code for `sum`. Could you post your average method insead?

Comment: errm. you have accepted an answer that deals with `average`, yet the questrion is regarding `sum`. Is the problem resolved? If so please update the question so that it makes sense for future references. (I am not disagreeing with the accepted answer)

Comment: @AvadaKedavra, fixed as per your recommendation for clarity. Lemme know if I should do anything different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`average()` has divided something by zero and got minus infinity, and that's how `cout` has displayed it.

Answer (score 3):

Divide-by-zero is well-defined to be positive or negative infinity. By default this displays as

```
Inf
```

or

```
-Inf
```

(at least on my machine).

`setprecison` messes this up, [see this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541975/what-does-1-mean).

Answer (score -1):

You failed to show the average method but my guess is that you do a divide by zero in there. Wackiness ensues.