# What is the meaning of `-1.$e+000`?

Tags: c++

What is the meaning of the symbol `-1.$e+000`? In what category are these kind of things included or with what keywords I can search them?

[image]

**EDIT**: After increasing precision this is what I got:

[image]

Comment: It's not really a "symbol" per se. I suppose that depends on what abstraction layer you're talking about, though. :)

Comment: Could you be more explicit please?

Comment: Not without knowing which direction you want me to be more explicit in. What do you want to know?

Comment: Now, where did you see `-1.$e+000`? Can you show us?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean

Comment: I didn't want a screenshot. You might as well have scribbled it on a piece of paper and taken a photograph. >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see `-1.#INF`, `-1.#IND` and similar text for formatted numerical output, [you're on Microsoft Visual Studio and you're seeing a special floating-point type that cannot be represented by a number](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html)... that is, either *infinity* or *NaN* ("not a number").

[You can get the variant `-1.#J` by specifying precision in `printf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840081/what-does-floating-point-error-1-j-mean), and [you can get `-1.$` by specifying low precision in iostreams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541975/what-does-1-mean/5542066#5542066).

The `e+000` is just a suffix from scientific notation, indicating an exponent of `0`. It's safely ignored.

On Linux GCC you tend to see the text `inf` and `nan` instead.

Comment: @mskfisher: I certainly didn't intend for this answer to overtake yours.. It was supposed to be an addendum! Sorry ;(

Answer (score 6):

[That symbol is the Windows representation of NaN](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html).

Comment: The original question asked about `-1.#INF` and, after I answered, was edited to `-1.$e+000`, which is not mentioned in the article I linked.  I'm not sure they are the same.

Comment: [Looks like NaN from Windows, with precision set small and a scientific exponent suffix.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5542066/560648)

Comment: The edit history doesn't confirm that, but somehow I believe it's true.

Comment: @Daniel: It might have been edited within the five-minute grace period.

Comment: The edit history doesn't show edits made within the first 5 minutes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44174/edited-answer-does-not-show-edited-or-history-link

Comment: That's why I didn't disbelieve it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Nondisbeliever

Comment: @Lightness I don't believe that.

Comment: @Daniel: I hope you're not dissing