# Does C++11 allow dollar signs in identifiers?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, identifier

[Are dollar-signs allowed in identifiers in C++03?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936744/are-dollar-signs-allowed-in-identifiers-in-c03) covers that dollar signs in identifiers are not allowed in C++03. GCC provides it as a [C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs) and properly gives a diagnostic in C++03 mode. However, in C++11, `int $ = 0` will compile without warning.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16055409/3920237) reasons that `$` may be allowed because no diagnostic is required for implementation defined identifiers:

> The answer here is **"Maybe"**:    According to **§2.11**, identifiers
>   may consist of *digits* and *identifier-nondigits*, starting with one
>   of the latter. *identifier-nondigits* are the usual `a-z`, `A-Z` and
>   underscore, in addition since C++11 they include
>   *universal-character-names* (e.g. `\uBEAF`, `\UC0FFEE32`), **and other implementation-defined characters**. So it is implementation defined
>   if using `$` in an identifier is allowed. VC10 and up supports that,
>   maybe earlier versions, too. It even supports identifiers like
>   `こんばんわ`.
>
> **But:** I wouldn't use them. Make identifiers as readable and portable as possible. `$` is implementation defined and thus not
>   portable.

This language is present in the C++03 standard as well, so I don't find this to be a very convincing argument.

§2.10/2

> In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C ++
>   implementations and standard libraries (17.6.4.3.2) and shall not be
>   used otherwise; no diagnostic is required.

What change in the standard allows `$` to be used as an identifier name?

Comment: Clang warns on this.

Comment: @Shafik Confusingly enough this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14595459/3920237) links to old gcc documentation that explicitly says that C++ forbids `$` in identifiers. They moved it to [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) with the only description `Accept ‘$’ in identifiers.`

Comment: Historically, DEC used $ in all of its system service and library function names with $$ in all of its internal functions. All the DEC compilers either extensions allowing $ symbol names or pragmas for mapping (as with ADA).

Comment: With GCC 4.9.2, I found that $ seems to be allowed except as the first character. That really surprised me. I first saw this used recently in the hilarious BASIC emulator at https://github.com/rollbear/basicp. I looked at the source to find out how on earth the $ symbol was supported. Surprisingly: natively! But, obviously, $ should be avoided as it does not seem to be standard or portable. (On the other hand, GCC didn't like £. Boo!)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is implementation defined behavior, `$` is not included in grammar for identifiers. The rules for identifier names in *C++11* are:

1. It can not start with a number
2. Can be composed of letters, numbers, underscore, universal character names and *implementation defined* characters
3. Can not be a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)

*Implementation-defined characters* are allowed and many compilers support as an extension, including [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs), `clang`, [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx) and as noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301737/does-c11-allow-dollar-signs-in-identifiers#comment41275143_26301737) apparently [DEC C++ compilers](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/c/cplusplus/cxx570_ug_003.html#index_x_142).

The grammar is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.11` *Indentifier*, I added additional notes starting with `<-`:

```
identifier:
  identifier-nondigit            <- Can only start with a non-digit
  identifier identifier-nondigit <- Next two rules allows for subsequent 
  identifier digit               <-  characters to be those outlined in 2 above
identifier-nondigit:
  nondigit                       <- a-z, A-Z and _ 
  universal-character-name
  other implementation-defined characters
[...]
```

If we compile this code using `clang` with the `-pedantic-errors` flag it will not compile:

```
int $ = 0
```

and generates the following error:

```
error: '$' in identifier [-Werror,-Wdollar-in-identifier-extension]
int $ = 0;
    ^
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. Dollar sign is in ASCII 0x24, which is not inside any of the ranges defined in appendix E.1 (charname.allowed) of the standard. And since it is neither digit nor nondigit it must be an implementation-defined character. I aggree thus that this is not portable C++11. Also note that an identifier shall not start with a universal-character, while it does allow an identifier to start with an character allowed by the implementation.

Comment: "Not portable" and "not allowed" (ill-formed) are both bad things, but not the same. So this isn't a direct answer to the question.

Comment: I am well aware of that. I used "not portable" as a synonym for "implementation-defined behaviour"here.