# Use @$? symbols in a C function/variable

Tags: c, symbols, debug-symbols

I'm curious if there's any way to use @, $, or ? in a C function or variable name. I know that linkers allow them (because of C++ name mangling).

Is there any kind of escape code that could allow this (I don't care how ugly it looks)? Or, in standard C, is this completely impossible?

Comment: Maybe but why would that be good?

Comment: [dollar sign is supported as an extension by gcc, clang and Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26302259/1708801)

Comment: @iharob I'm just curious if this is possible or not :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible in purely standard C.

But if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (or probably [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)) you can have  [`$` in identifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html#Dollar-Signs), and you can set the linker name using [`asm` labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels)

You could perhaps also play [GNU ld](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) tricks with [ld scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts).

Comment: Could you give an example of setting the linker name using `asm`?

Comment: I just edited my answer to link to the documentation

Answer (score 5):

Standard C does not allow any of these (and it can't really allow `?` since it's an operator and thus a separate token). GCC (and possibly compatible compilers) allow `$` but not the others. However, you could use the GNU C (GCC) extension for making a declaration for an external-linkage name that references a different underlying symbol name; this may achieve what you want, e.g. if you're trying to reference C++ symbols. I believe the syntax is something like adding `__asm__("symbol_name")` to the end of the function declaration. There are some examples in the glibc headers on most Linux systems.

Alternatively, if you have `dlsym`, you could use it to look up the names at runtime.